# How to add floating button in react native?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native

I want to add floating button in react native. I have added it with `position: absolute` but it is shown at the end i.e at the botto of the screen. Currently it is only displayed at the bottom i.e where the content of the screen ends. I want to display floating button on bottom right corner and should be visible when user scrolls the screen up and down.

Floating button from react native paper: https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/fab.html#usage

If I use position: 'fixed' then it gives me error https://i.stack.imgur.com/aw462.jpg

Code:

```
<ScrollView>

// Some other View components 

     <FAB
        style={styles.fab}
        small
        color="#00d048"
        icon="add"
      />
</ScrollView>
```

CSS:

```
fab: {
        position: 'absolute',
        right: 0,
        bottom: 0,
    }
```

In the screenshot you can see the button is not floating over the content instead it is displayed at bottom of the screen.

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

React Native does not currently support `position: fixed`, so we have to add the element in a separate `View` with absolute position. As we still want to scroll the other content, we will have to wrap these two in another `View`:

```
<View style={{flex: 1}}>
  <ScrollView>
   // Your other components here
  </ScrollView>
  <View style={styles.fixedView}>
    <Fab
      style={styles.fab}
      small
      color="#00d048"
      icon="add"
     />
  </View>
</View>
```

And the styling:

```
fixedView : {
  position: 'absolute',
  left: 0,
  bottom: 0,
  flexDirection: 'row',
  justifyContent: 'flex-end',
}
```

Optionally give a neat margin to the right and bottom of the `Fab`

```
fab: {
    margin-right: theme.spacing.unit * 2,
    margin-bottom: theme.spacing.unit * 3,
}
```

Comment: If I use position: 'fixed' then I get this check this https://imgur.com/a/JZJ7Pbl

Comment: Good point @funjoker React Native does not support `position: fixed` as ReactJS does. Let me know if the updated approach works for you.

Comment: If I want to add icon on bottom left corner also then how can I do that ?

Comment: Add it to the fixedView, specify `justifyContent: space-between` instead of `flex-end` and remove the `margin-right` from `fab`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `position: absolute;` parent must be `position: relative;`

Comment: There are some differences between the CSS defaults and React Native ones. For example, `position: relative` is the default in React Native whereas for CSS it is `static`. Not all styling properties are available in React Native either.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons

```
import {TouchableOpacity, Image} from 'react-native';

<TouchableOpacity
          style={{
            borderWidth: 1,
            borderColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.2)',
            alignItems: 'center',
            justifyContent: 'center',
            width: 70,
            position: 'absolute',
            bottom: 30,
            right: 10,
            height: 70,
            backgroundColor: '#fff',
            borderRadius: 100,
          }}
        >
          {/* <Icon name="plus" size={30} color="#01a699" /> */}
          <Image style={{width: 50, height:50,  resizeMode: 'contain'}} source={require('assets/imgs/group.png')} />
        </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
```